# Does the BurntToast module for powershell work for windows 11?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm on windows 11, and i'm using VMs that take lot of resources. So i want to write a script that prompted me if the free RAM memory space is lower than 1.5GB, and i was told to use the BurntToast module (designed for windows 10 and server 2019).

Before breaking anything, i want to know if it's fine to use it for windows 11.

Comment: The fastest way to find out is to try :) There's nothing "dangerous" in the module, worst case it just doesn't work